# How to write multiline commands in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and linux world. Question looks very simple but I'm having tough time writing some long commands in console.
Say, I have to run some active record queries to see the results in console, below line works perfect

```
User.find(1)
```

But I can't type below query as last 3 characters simply gets truncated

```
Category.includes(:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags]).find(1)
```

or something weird happens like below

```
nd(1)-p327 :009 > Category.includes(:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags]).fin
```

What I need to do to get it work?

Comment: What terminal? Never seen anything like this-define "gets truncated", are you saying that the statement doesn't execute, or you just can't see all of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you end a line with a period IRB will assume it is a multi-line command:

```
Category.
includes(:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags]).
find(1)
```

It's odd that it's getting truncated though. Which terminal application are you using?